# C# - perform addition while calling a method

Tags: c#

I am taking a course in C# (beginner) and one of my assignments require me to make a method inside a class that would make this line work:

```
string n = Calculator.WriteNumber(53 + 28);
Console.WriteLine(n);
```

I can do it like this:

```
string n = Calculator.WriteNumber(53, 28);
Console.WriteLine(n);
```

when my method is defined like this:

```
public static string WriteNumber(int a, int b) 
{
    int result = a + b;
    string output = result.ToString();
    return output;
}
```

But is it possible to do what my assignment requires, i.e. pass `a+b` to the method, instead of `a,b`?

What would the method look like if that is possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: as your teacher say you most have a method with one parameter and then call that like this *Calculator.WriteNumber(53 + 28);*  and the method is like this  *public static string WriteNumber(int result){return result.Tostring();}*

Comment: Technically the "add" operation is just a function call with some Syntax Sugar to not **look** like a function call. And often it is interned too, so it will not even appear like that in MSIL code. You can overload most operators to have "more natural" semantics in code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators

Comment: @Christopher Not sure that mentioning IL code, operators overloading and syntax sugar in a comment on a question when admittedly OP is just getting started with the language (and maybe programming in general) is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there anything wrong with doing this?

```
public static string WriteNumber(int x)
{
    string output = x.ToString();
    return output;
}
```

You code then runs and produces `81`.

Comment: @Enigmativity what is the reason for having this method at all if we will just return a .ToString() without any extra logic?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy Because that's what the assignment requires. It's common for assignments for beginners to ask for something that would normally be useless. For beginners, the practice of creating the function itself may be useful.

Comment: @hvd yes, you are right, but I think it worth mentioning for beginners the truth as well and that this is not the way to do it in real life

Answer (score 1):

You have got what you want, but the function is nearly doing nothing.

You could enhance it a little to add n numbers passed in parameters:

```
public static string WriteNumber(params int[] x)
       {
         int sum = 0;
        foreach(int a in x)
        {
         sum += a;
        }
        return sum.ToString();
}
```

And call it like

```
var output =WriteNumber(1,2,3,4);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
```

You just have to now deal with exception which can come if adding numbers exceeds `int.MaxValue`

Comment: Thanks, @Surjit SD. Having arrays in methods is a bit advanced for my level at this stage... But thanks for the tip!